# Insert a string into a string given an index

Tags: php, string

I know this is a really simple question, but I was just wondering if there is `a native php method to inject a string into another string`.  My usual response to a new text manipulation is to consult the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php)'s listings of string functions. But I didn't see any native methods for explicitly inserting a string into another string so I figured i'd consult SO.

The answer is likely some kind of combination of the php native string functions OR simply regex (which makes my eye's bleed and my brain melt so I avoid it).

EX:
Take a string like `some-image.jpg` and inject `.big` before `.jpg` yielding `some-image.big.jpg`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[You can do anything with regular expressions](http://xkcd.com/208/)!

For your specific request, the solution would be:

```
$var = 'myimage.jpg';
$new_var = preg_replace('/\.jpg$/', '.big$0', $var);
```

I would suggest reading up on how to write regular expressions, as they can be very useful in development ([here's a starting point](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)).

Comment: lol refer to my eye's bleeding comment.  I'm not opposed to using regex, just writing it!!! haha.  Although I've come to terms with the fact that I need to buck up and learn it better.

Comment: my eye's hatred for regex aside... this is a superb tutorial on regex - http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/regular-expressions-part1---basic-syntax

Comment: @Derek http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html if you want to learn regex better ;)

Answer (score 24):

You can use [`substr_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) to insert a string by replacing a zero-length substring with your insertion:

```
$string = "some-image.jpg";
$insertion = ".big";
$index = 10;

$result = substr_replace($string, $insertion, $index, 0);
```

From the manual page (the description of the `length` (4th) argument):

> If length is zero then this function will have the effect of inserting replacement  into string at the given start offset.

Comment: Much better answer IMO. Using a regex for something as simple as this is overkill

Comment: This assumes that we know the index. We probably don't... so yeah, regex

Comment: The question stated *given an index*. :)

Answer (score 7):

See this: http://www.krizka.net/2007/12/29/how-to-insert-a-string-into-another-string-in-php/

```
$newstring=substr_replace($orig_string, $insert_string, $position, 0);
```