# PHP preg_match to check image

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am working with wordpress images that the user chooses.  They may or may not have been resized by wordpress and have their size added on to the end of the image like so:

original image:  image.jpg
wordpress version: image-300x200.jpg

How would I search to see if the image has this added to it?  The easiest way would be to check if it has an 'x' 8 characters from the end of the variable but then there is the off chance that the image could actually have an x in it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thy this:

```
$is_resized=preg_match('|^.*-[0-9]{1,4}x[0-9]{1,4}\..*$|',$imagename)
```

Comment: Oh thank you.  One more question, how would I add a string 4 characters from the end of another string?

Comment: answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704310/insert-a-string-into-a-string-given-an-index

Comment: Only problem is it might not be .jpg, it could be .png or .gif

Comment: if you read carefully all answers of the link i gave , some are more generic. moreover, by replacing the .*$ part of the regexp i gave you by (.*)$ and using the $matches param of preg_match, you'll get the image extension and could be able to perform a seach for insert with it